# How to normalize Sprite movement in Java2D graphics to account for Screen Resolution

Tags: javafx-8, graphics2d

I am trying to build a 2D video game using JavaFX.  There is a submarine at the bottom of the screen that fires torpedos. I have noticed that if I fire a torpedo on an Angle it travels at a faster rate, than if say I fired it straightup where is goes directly North.  I'm assuming the difference in rates is because the screen is a rectangle, and when moving on a diagonal you are covering more distance.

Are there techniques to account for this, so you can get a constant rate of movement, regardless of the angle of travel of the projectile?  I am writing the game using JavaFX under Eclipse.

Appreciate any help with this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already firing in different directions, I'm assuming you have a velocity vector defined by two components `(x, y)`. In JavaFX such a vector can be represented by `Point2D`. Given the `speed` you want the projectile to travel at, you can do the following:

```
public void fire() {
    // the point at which you are shooting
    Point2D target = ...

    // the point from where you are shooting
    Point2D source = ...

    // the projectile speed per frame
    double speed = ...

    // velocity vector to be used to move
    // the projectile at constant speed per frame
    Point2D velocity = target.subtract(source).normalize().multiply(speed);
}
```

UPDATE: (included vector generation from angle)

In case you do not know the target point, you can obtain the vector from the angle you use to shoot:

```
public void fire() {
    double angleDegrees = ...
    double angleRadians = Math.toRadians(angleDegrees);

    // the point from where you are shooting
    Point2D source = ...

    // the projectile speed per frame
    double speed = ...

    Point2D shootingVector = new Point2D(Math.cos(angleRadians), Math.sin(angleRadians));

    // velocity vector to be used to move
    // the projectile at constant speed per frame
    Point2D velocity = shootingVector.normalize().multiply(speed);
}
```

Comment: Hi AlmasB, I am a complete newbie with Vector Math.  I do have an x,y coordinate of the sub.  I would like to fire the torpedo at fixed angles (30, 45, 90, etc).  How do I generate the path the torpedo will take using your input of Speed with this method of fire()?  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please see updated answer. You might need to adjust the Y axis, since in graphics we deal with positive Y being down and in math the positive Y is up.

Comment: Hi AlmasB, so being a NewBie at Vector Math, the shootingVector will contain the X and Y incremental movements that the projective needs to follow, given I have specified an angle for the projectile and it's speed? (I am looking to generate the array of x,y points that the projective would need to follow)  Thanks!